# Wierd Lid close/open and suspend problem

Tags: 14.04, suspend, laptop, power-management

I have an old Thinkpad W510. The pm-suspend works, the lid close then suspend does not.

After some searching, I found the following solution.

1. create /etc/acpi/events/lid (there's no lid related events, even the power management settings did set lid close to suspend)

the content is:

```
event=button/lid
action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh %e
```

2. I then create lid.sh as follows,

> ```
> echo "$1" | grep "button/lid" && grep -q open /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state && exit 0
> pm-suspend
> ```

It shoud mean that, when lid/LID/state is open, then exit, otherwise, suspend.

However, the behavior is wierd now. When I close the lid, it does enter into suspend. But when I open the lid, it first wakes up from suspend, and then enters into suspend again (I have to press power button to wake it up from the auto-suspend after open)

I tried some other ways of writing the above lid.sh, such as,

```
grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
fi
```

It's exactly the same behavior.

Anyone can show me any hints on why it behaves like "open the lid" -> "wake up" -> "suspend again immediately" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. 
I was able to solve it by editing the file /etc/systemd/logind.conf

There is a line *#HandleLidSwitch=suspend* you can uncomment the line by deleting the # sign and change the value to *poweroff, ignore, or suspend* depending on what you want.

Maybe this does not cause the side effect you are experiencing. It worked for me.

I created a script to change the value more quickly. 
https://github.com/andreshazard/lidBehaviourScript